# Why do I keep on getting an error message even though libssl-dev is installed?

Tags: rust, openssl, rust-cargo, rust-crates, libssl

I have a rust project that uses the below crate.

```
reqwest = { version = "0.11.18", features = ["blocking", "json"] }
```

In order to make it work, I installed "libssl-dev" using the below command in the terminal.

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

However, when I tried to run the project using the command `cargo run`, I got the below error message.

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.90`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/user/rust/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-cb188c5370e333b3/build-script-main` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR = /usr/include/openssl

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'OpenSSL include directory does not exist: /usr/include/openssl/include', /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-sys-0.9.90/build/main.rs:80:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

This should not happen since openssl is already installed. How do I make it work?

I tried to add the code `export OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/include/openssl` to the file "/.bashrc" in the home directory but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Based on the output you should not set OPENSSL_DIR but instead OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR to /usr/include/openssl